How to add executables of "assertAll()" to a list and execute them at the end of the test method?
The following JUnit Jupiter Tests with Mockito are working fine:
    @Test
    void testVerifMethod() {
        System.out.println("*** Start test verify method ***");

        mockedList.add("first-element");
        mockedList.add("second item");
        mockedList.add("third element");
        mockedList.add("4th string");
        mockedList.add("fifth item");
        mockedList.add("string added twice");
        mockedList.add("string added twice");
        mockedList.clear();

        assertAll("Verify all interactions:", 
                () -> verify(mockedList).add("first-element"),
                () -> verify(mockedList).add("4th string"),
                () -> verify(mockedList).add("fifth item"),
                () -> verify(mockedList, VerificationModeFactory.times(2)).add("string added twice"),
                () -> verify(mockedList).clear()
        );
    }

    @Test
    void mockStaticTest() {
        System.out.println("*** Started mockStaticTest ***");
        UUID myuuID = UUID.randomUUID();
        System.out.println("My Random UUID = " + myuuID.toString());
        UUID randomuuID1 = UUID.randomUUID();
        System.out.println("Random UUID 1 = " + randomuuID1.toString());
        UUID randomuuID2 = UUID.randomUUID();
        System.out.println("Random UUID 2 = " + randomuuID2.toString());

        assertAll("Testing multiple UUIDs before Mock Static:",
                () -> assertThat(randomuuID1, is(not(myuuID))),
                () -> assertThat(randomuuID2, is(not(myuuID)))
        );
        

        assertThat(UUID.randomUUID(), is(not(myuuID)));

        try (MockedStatic<UUID> uuidMock = Mockito.mockStatic(UUID.class)) {
            System.out.println("Now using Mock Static ...");
            uuidMock.when(UUID::randomUUID).thenReturn(myuuID);
            UUID mockeduuID1 = UUID.randomUUID();
            UUID mockeduuID2 = UUID.randomUUID();
            UUID mockeduuID3 = UUID.randomUUID();
            System.out.println("Mock Static 1 = " + mockeduuID1);
            System.out.println("Mock Static 2 = " + mockeduuID2);
            System.out.println("Mock Static 3 = " + mockeduuID3);

            assertAll("After Mock Static: ",
                    () -> assertThat(mockeduuID1, is(myuuID)),
                    () -> assertThat(mockeduuID2, is(myuuID)),
                    () -> assertThat(mockeduuID3, is(myuuID))
            );
        }
    }

I tried to add the executables of the assertAll() method to an ArrayList but it is not working. I am getting the compilation error "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface" on this line "assertions.add( ()-> .... )":
private List<Executable> assertions = new ArrayList<>();
...
...

assertions.add(() -> verify(mockedList).add("first-element"));
...
...
assertions.add(() -> assertThat(mockeduuID1, is(myuuID)));

How I can gather the assertions in a list and execute them at the end of the test method?
I tried so many variations of the above, and the compilation error won't go away!

Make sure you import Executable from the right source.
import org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable;

IntelliJ suggests importing the one from java.lang.reflect. Tried it myself, and it seems that the FunctionalInterface error comes from there.
List<Executable> exec = new ArrayList<>();
exec.add(() -> Mockito.verify(list).add("Test"));
exec.add(() -> Mockito.verify(list).add("Test2"));
exec.add(() -> Mockito.verify(list).add("Test3"));

Assertions.assertAll(exec);

This should now do the job. Syntactically, your approach was correct.

Wow! I'll check it out and provide and update!
